# Dudas DDD y background services

Tags: c#, .net, ddd

Tengo un micro servicio en net 8 que arroja un evento de integración con apache kafka, ese evento lo quiero manejar en otro servicio mediante un brackground services.

¿La duda que tengo es que en que capa(aplicación, infraestructura, dominio) iría la implementación de ese background services?, y En que capa iría el DTO que uso para el mapeo de los datos recibidos desde el evento de integración?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!